# Upgraded to 15.10 and cds wouldn't play anymore. Reverted to 15.04 and cds play. Any way to get cds to play in 15.10?

Tags: 15.10

Upgraded to 15.10 and cds wouldn't play.  Reverted to 15.04 and cds played.  Any way to get cds to play in 15.10?  I like other items in 15.10 and would prefer it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi install the Ubuntu restricted add on available in the software center

Comment: @fabby I answered before anyone like you will see if you arrange it by the oldest post first....thanks for the welcome just weird how people are on this site lol who cares about rep people take others answers etc crazy

Comment: sorry...  If you would include a screenshot it would make it a good answer! (dumb comment deleted and +1)

Answer (score 1):

In terminal use the following command:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

You will be prompted for your password, type it (you won't see it) and hit enter. After installing the extras you will be able to play cds.

Comment: Did that thru Software Center after installation and it made no difference.  DVDs could be played fine.  Cds were not even recognized as being in the tray.